# Using quantopian for data analysis

Tags: python-3.x, zipline

I want to know were Quantopian gets data from?

If I want to do an analysis on a stock market other than NYSE, will I get the data? If not, can I manually upload the data so that I can run my algorithms on it.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Quantopian gets its data from several places, and provides most [online](https://www.quantopian.com/data) although some are premium and require subscription.

2.) Yes, you can get standard stock market data, but if you have something like a Bloomberg, other subscription or something else you've built and want to pull it in, you can use fetcher.

The basic code is:

```
fetch_csv(url, pre_func=None, post_func=None, date_column='date',  
           date_format='%m/%d/%y', timezone='UTC', symbol=None, **kwargs)
```

Here is an example for something like Dropbox:

```
def initialize(context):  
    # fetch data from a CSV file somewhere on the web.
    # Note that one of the columns must be named 'symbol' for 
    # the data to be matched to the stock symbol
    fetch_csv('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/169032081/fetcher_sample_file.csv', 
           date_column = 'Settlement Date',
           date_format = '%m/%d/%y')  
    context.stock = symbol('NFLX')

def handle_data(context, data):    
    record(Short_Interest = data.current(context.stock, 'Days To Cover'))
```

Comment: If I have data saved locally on my machine what should I do to use it in Zipline module.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data for non-NYSE stocks as well like Nasdaq securities.  Screens are also available by fundamentals(market, exchange, market cap).  These screens can limit stocks analyzed from the broad universe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get stock data from Yahoo or other [quant](https://bigquant.com/) sites.